# Как отключить автоокругление поля типа float?

Tags: php, mysql, float

Друзья ситуация такая. В БД есть поле типа float. Когда я вношу в него данные вручную, либо через скрипт, к примеру 7.77 почему то в ячейке становится 7.8 . Получается что существует какое-то авто округление. Как его можно отключить?

```
7.78 = > 7.8
```

Comment: Может в БД определить тип как `FLOAT(5,2)`  то есть 5 (цифра из головы - означает общую длину) из которых 2 знака после запятой, или сколько вам надо. А вообще Float не самый точный тип. Если нужна точность хорошая, надо бы использовать Decimal

Comment: Спасибо большое! Наверное как вы говорите лучше буду использовать Decimal